# Wait until socket as service gets available

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, socket.io

I have read about Thread sleep, Handler, Runnable, AsyncTask and TimerTask, tried Thread sleep but could not figure out how can I accomplish the task.

I have implemented [socket.io.client-java](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) as service and using Volley as well as multiple activities & fragments. I need as follow:

- Check if socket is connected before making Volley request.
- If socket is connected then process Volley request otherwise re-check socket connectivity (a maximum of 5 times with 1 second interval).
- In case of failure in 5 attempts, show a Toast message and continue the Volley request.

I 'm using a common class to perform Volley requests and others.

**Socket Service**

```
public class SocketClient extends Service {

private Socket mSocket = null;
private static SocketClient iSocket;

public SocketClient() {
    super();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    iSocket = this;
    startSocket();
}

public static synchronized SocketClient getInstance(){return iSocket;}

private void startSocket(){        

    try {
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                //...
            }

        }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                //...
            }

        }).on(...{...});

        mSocket.connect();

    } catch (URISyntaxException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public boolean isConnected(){ return (mSocket != null && mSocket.connected()); }

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    mSocket.disconnect().close();
    mSocket = null;
}
}
```

**Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    Helpers.startServices(getApplicationContext(), 1);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Helpers.getNotifed();   //A Volley Request
}
```

**Helpers Class**

```
public static void makeReq(Map<String, Object> params, String api, final Context context, final VolleyListener listener)
{
    manager = new SessionManager(context);
    final String url = baseURL + api;

    int i = 0;
    boolean ss = SocketClient.getInstance().isConnected();
    Log.i(TAG, "Socket status" + ss);
    while(i < 5 && !ss) {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Socket status" + ss);
            Log.i(TAG, "sleeping " + i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            ss = SocketClient.getInstance().isConnected();
            i++;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(!ss)
        Toast.makeText(context, "Operation interrupt!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    //Volley JSON Object Request
}    

public static void startServices(Context context, int st) {
    switch (st) {
        case 1: //Socket
            if (!isServiceRunning(context, SocketClient.class))
                context.startService(new Intent(context, SocketClient.class));
            break;            
    }
}
```

Issues:

- Getting NullPointerException at `boolean ss =  SocketClient.getInstance().isConnected();` as class might not initialized yet.
- ANR (Application Not Responding) because the main Thread is halted in while loop.

P.S.: I'm just a beginner in Android/Java so reply with clear code would be appreciable.

Comment: `Socket mSocket`. That is no Socket.IO.

Comment: @greenapps I didn't get you. Would you clear it? BTW I have removed import statements for clarity,

Comment: Well is that a socket from socket io? It looks like a  java Socket.

Comment: Yes it's socket from socket io.